# Get a c++11 function wrapper for a member function without using std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement a basic signal/slots system. Everything is up and running but I'm trying to improve the usability of my implementation.

At the moment this is how you connect to a signal:

```
struct X
{
    void memberFunction(int a, int b)
    {
         // do something
    }
};

void globalStaticFunction(int a, int b)
{
    // do something
}

// this is what the signal::connect function looks like at the moment
ConnectionHandle connect(std::function<RetType(Args...)> func);


int main()
{
    // test instance
    X x;

    // example signal
    Signal<void(int, int)> mySignal;


    // connect a static function to the signal
    mySignal.connect(&globalStaticFunction);

    // connect a member function
    // here we have to use std::bind to get a std::function
    mySignal.connect(std::bind(&X::memberFunction, &x, _1, _2));
}
```

I would like to supply the user with an easier way to bind member functions. I had something like this in mind (similar to how Qt does it):

```
// prefered member function connect
// connect(instance_ptr, function_ptr)
mySignal.connect(&x, &X::memberFunction);
```

Is it possible to get a std::function object for a member function without using std::bind? If not, is there an easy way to generate the std::bind call with just the instance_ptr and the function_ptr for the member function?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216762/partial-binding-of-function-arguments for some thoughts on partial binding of functions (which is basically what you're trying to do here). Unfortunately, there's nothing like that in the standard library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a member of `Signal`:

```
template<typename C>
ConnectionHandle connect( C* c, RetType(C::*func)(Args...)) {
  return connect( [c,func](Args&&...args) {
    return (c->*func)( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  });
}

template<typename C, typename Method, typename... Unused>
ConnectionHandle connect( C* c, Method* m, Unused&&...) {
  return connect( [c,func](Args&&...args) {
    return (c->*m)( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  });
}
```

The first overload gives you the ability to distinguish between overloaded methods.

The second, if the first fails, lets you use signature-compatible methods.

The `...` portion makes sure the first is a better match if they both match (I hope!)

`Args&&...` should work with a `std::function`, assuming the `std::function` properly perfect forwards.  If not, replace with `Args...`.

I see no need for `bind` or variants, given that we are going to stuff it into a `std::function` immediately anyhow.  Create a lambda, they are well suited to the task.

Comment: Oh, lambdas.  How simple!

Comment: @MooingDuck Not bound members -- value arguments!  `std::function<A(B)>` should `std::forward<B>(b)` its one argument, so storing a `[](B&&)` in it should work.  If `B` is a value, forward produces an rvalue -- if `B` is a reference, `B&&` reference decays nicely.

Comment: I have just started to transition over to c++11 and never really used boost. I'm blown away with what you can do with lambdas, your solution is very elegant indeed. I have just one concern: So if I understand how lambdas work correctly, then the lambda in your example creates an extra class that takes c and func as arguments in the constructor. The lambda function is then a member of this class and in turn calls func on the c pointer. Is it possible that this affects performance in any way?

Comment: Also on an other note, I read [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) article about lambdas among others to get up to speed. And the author was calling static functions 'functions' and member functions 'methods'. Is this a common way of referencing functions today? Coming from java (standard in my uni) I always used the two interchangeably.

Comment: Update on the performance: I did some very simple tests comparing the run times of callbacks bound by using std::bind and the ones using your lambda solution. I timed 100Mil calls for Release and 1Mil for Debug. In Debug mode the lambda solution is consistently ~20% faster. But most STL stuff has poor performance in Debug mode (I'm working with VS2013 btw). In release mode both solutions perform about the same (+-1%), which is awesome.

Comment: @derkie The lambda creates a function object -- but that is also how `bind` works.  Calling a free function a "method" would confuse someone in C++.

Comment: @derkie: On vocabulary (IMO): "Function" can refer to any sort of functions unless specified in a particular context.  If the article says he only uses the term for static functions, that's fine, but only applies to his paper.  Both static and non-static Member functions are called "methods" in many languages, but also "functions" sometimes.  "Free functions" (functions not part of classes, like main in C++) are almost never called methods in C++.

Answer (score 3):

## This trick is good in C++03, but for C++11 please use Yakk's answer.

Something akin to this probably does the trick.

First: Make a SIMPLE version of `bind` that only binds the `this`.

```
template<class T, class RetType, class...Args>
RetType CallMemFn(T* obj, RetType(T::*func)(Args...), Args...args)
{return ((*obj).*(func))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}

template<class T, class RetType, class...Args>
struct boundthis {
    typedef RetType result_type;
    typedef T* thistype;
    typedef RetType(*signature)(Args...);
    boundthis(T* self, RetType(T::*func)(Args...)) :self(self), func(func) {}
    RetType operator()(Args...args) {return CallMemFn(self,func,std::forward<Args>(args)...);}
private:
    T* self;
    RetType(T::*func)(Args...);
};
template<class T, class RetType, class...Args>
boundthis<T,RetType,Args...> bindthis(T* self, RetType(T::*func)(Args...))
{return boundthis<T,RetType,Args...>(self, func);}
```

And finally, the wrapper you desire:

```
template<class T, class RetType, class...Args>
ConnectionHandle connect(T* obj, RetType(T::*func)(Args...))
{return connect(std::function<RetType(Args...)>(bindthis(obj, func)));}
```

http://ideone.com/a2rze0

Comment: As an aside, I think the OP doesn't want to use `bind` external to the interface: I suspect internal use of `bind` would be acceptable...

Comment: @Yakk: Absolutely, except, [bind can't bind easily bind only the first argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216762/partial-binding-of-function-arguments)  (See Rev1 of my answer)